# ERROR: No cached version listing for io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+ available for offline mode

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hello i am facing this Problem while running my code Can please someone help to solve this issue here is below my Gradle Code

App Level Gadle Code

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
 }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.jinito"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 45
    versionName '1.45'
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
signingConfigs {
    debugConfig {
        storeFile file("debug.keystore");
        storePassword("android");
        keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
        keyPassword "android";
    }
    releaseConfig {
        storeFile file("JinittoApp.jks");
        storePassword("jui&84GA~4fM");
        keyAlias "JinittoAndroidAppKey2017"
        keyPassword "lW73_k9sX12";
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "isDebug", "true"
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "isDebug", "false"
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors {
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.wx.wheelview:wheelview:1.3.3'
compile files('libs/autobanh.jar')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:4.0.1'
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile project(path: ':linkedin-sdk')
compile project(path: ':checkmobi_sdk')
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
//    compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.3.0'
implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.0'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project Level Gradle Code

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files}
  }
  allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
 }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

i have followed the previous sollutions given by other people but it doesnt worked for my Please if someone know sollution to it please let me know

Thanks

Comment: You're in offline mode.

Comment: Goto **File -> settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment** -> Then uncheck -> **Offline work** on the right. then rebuild your project

Comment: did the same here is another problem

Comment: ERROR: Read timed out

Comment: @Zoe I am facing antother problem ERROR: Read timed out

Comment: try to use 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.2' this instead of 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'